# OSX - use dmg as remote drive?

Tags: installation, osx-mountain-lion, diskimage

going to install Mountain Lion OSX to multiple iMacs, to reduce the internet usage and get faster instalation id like to instal it from local source - already downloaded the instaler to one machine and extracted the DMG from installer

now - is there a way to connect the dmg the way so it is available as remote drive to the machine where I want to install (over LAN)?

with Disc Sharing on i know the CD/DVD can be shared, any knowledge whether it works for DMG files too? maybe disk utility somehow?

the catch is I have it downloaded on a new iMac 27" without a real drive and there is no "Disc Sharing" option in the sharing settings

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I know of no way to natively use i.e. PXE for Macs, so one would have to use Apples own methods. There is one that I did not test myself, using netboot and netrestore. Here is a link to a KB article:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4178

Maybe this is a good starting point for more research?

Comment: hmm I may give it a try, if succes,  will report back

Comment: if I read right I need a OSX server with NetBoot which I dont, just a router with dhcp, and few iMac and MacBook machines on it  :(